# bootstrap 3 icon missing after upgrade into bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I find something good about sidebar menu with Bootstrap from [here](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar). I download the source code and then i replace old Bootstrap 3 into Bootstrap 4. But, i see some icon is gone or missing, not the glyphicon, but the icon cursor/arrow down like this. I try to replace it with Font Awesome, but it's not like what i expected. Is there's something i need to know before i replace BS3 with BS4 ?

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
        Home
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
        About
    </a>
    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>
        Pages
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see font awesome in your above code, just glyphicon. Look at the documentaion from Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#toggler

Comment: i'm not add Font awesome in here, because it not works, maybe i will edit my code with font awesome. And that code is code from the source.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 got rid of the glyphicons.From the offical BS docs "Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon library by default, but we have a handful of recommendations for you to choose from. While most icon sets include multiple file formats, we prefer SVG implementations for their improved accessibility and vector support.
Preferred
We’ve tested and used these icon sets ourselves.: Font Awesome, Iconic, Octicons
More options https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/extend/icons/

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3 that icons come  from:

```
 a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
```

And appeared automatically.

As glyphicons are dropped down in bootstrap 4 I think you have to set them manually in styles, using one of the suggested alternatives from the documentation

> If you need icons, some options are: the upstream version of Glyphicons,  Octicons, Font Awesome